# Localhost admin error: http://localhost:8080/magento2/

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

```
1 exception(s):
```

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magefan\Community\Observer\PredispathAdminActionControllerObserver does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magefan\Community\Observer\PredispathAdminActionControllerObserver does not exist

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magefan\Communit...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magefan\Communit...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magefan\Communit...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magefan\Communit...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\Event\ObserverFactory.php:33]
#5 Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverFactory->get('Magefan\Communit...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault.php:72]
#6 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Magefan\Communit...', 'name' => 'magefan_communit...'), &Magento\Framework\Event\Observer#000000003e0cc817000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php:66]
#7 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_actio...', array('controller_actio...' => &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e0ccbc5000000001e62f87d#, 'request' => &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#)) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy.php:95]
#8 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_actio...', array('controller_actio...' => &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e0ccbc5000000001e62f87d#, 'request' => &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php:97]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php:231]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php:143]
#13 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e0ccbc5000000001e62f87d#, &Closure#000000003e0ccbc4000000001e62f87d#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#), NULL) called at [generated\code\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor.php:39]
#16 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:162]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#, &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e0ccbc5000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:98]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php:26]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e0cc9f4000000001e62f87d#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:116]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000003e0cc99a000000001e62f87d#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: you run all commands

Comment: @MohitPatel When I tried to run the all cli commands showing an below error. # php bin/magento setup:di:compile
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer/../magefan/module-community/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 73  
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer/../magefan/module-community/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 73

Comment: first you remove vendor folder and second run `composer install` command